# Storing a very large array of strings in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to store a large array of strings in AWS to be used from my application. The requirements are as follows:

1. During normal operations, string elements will be added to the array and the array size will continue to grow
2. I need to enforce uniqueness - i.e. the same string cannot be stored twice
3. I will have to retrieve the entire array periodically - most probably to put it in a file and use it from the application
4. I need to backup the data (or at least be convinced that there is a good built-in backup system as part of the features)

I looked at the following:

1. RDS (MySQL) - this may be overkill and also may become uncomfortably large for a single table (millions of records).
2. DynamoDB - This is intended for key/value pairs, but I have only a single value per record. Also, and more importantly, retrieving a large number of records seems to be an issue in DynamoDB as the scan operation needs paging and also can be expensive in terms of capacity units, etc.
3. Single S3 file - This could be a practical solution except that I may need to write to the file (append) concurrently, and that is not a feature that is available in S3. Also, it would be hard to enforce the element uniqueness
4. DocumentDB - This seems to be too expensive and overkill for this purpose
5. ElastiCache - I don't have a lot of experience with this and wonder if it would be a good fit for my requirement and if it's practical to have it be backed up periodically. This also uses key/value pairs and it is not advisable to read millions of records (entire data) at the same time

Any insights or recommendations would be helpful.

Update:

I don't know why people are voting to close this. It is definitely a programming related question and I have already gotten extremely useful answers and comments that will help me and hopefully others in the future. Why is there such an obsession with opinionated closure of useful posts on SO?

Comment: Amazon ElastiCache may be helpful! https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/

Comment: @nmwalsh - thanks! I was editing my question and adding that at the same type you replied :)

Comment: Define 'large array' (how many items)? If you have no key into the strings, how are you accessing them (always as an array)?

Comment: @jarmod It will grow about one million items a year. I will always access the entire array to be used in a backend type application to do calculations a couple of times a day

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB might be a good fit.

It doesn't matter that you don't have any "value" to your "key". Just use the string as the primary key. That will also enforce uniqueness.

You get [on-demand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BackupRestore.html) and [continuous](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/PointInTimeRecovery.html) backups. I don't have experience with these so I can only point you to the documentation.

The full retrieval of the data might be the biggest hassle. It is not recommended to do a full-table SCAN with DynamoDB; it can get expensive. There's a way how to use Data Pipelines [to do an export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html) (I also have not used it). Alternatively, you could put together a system by yourself, utilizing DynamoDB [streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html), e.g. you can push a stream to Kinesis and then to S3.

Comment: I like the streams idea. He could create S3 files based off of new inserts into the table and that would alleviate the need for a full table scan. Constantly recreating the file could get expensive but that could be tuned or possibly sharded across a few files.

Comment: Thanks! So the "values" would be empty strings? Or can you store just keys? Another quick question if you don't mind: Is the Data Pipelines or streams solution practical to be used on demand by an application or are they intended for scheduled backups type of thing?

Comment: Yes, you can store just keys (it's only a "key" because you tell DynamoDB so when you create the table). What difference do you have in mind between scheduled and on demand backups? In any case, by my understanding, be a better use case for Data Pipelines export. The streams are continuous - every time a new item is added to the table, it will be also put to the stream, so you'd have to react to it constantly (streams have a 24h window after which they drop the data in them).